# Copy to restricted folder with Ant (using Eclipse in Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, eclipse, ant, ubuntu

Using Eclipse in Ubuntu Linux.

I'm creating an ant task to delete a directory in my apache localhost directory (/var/www) and then copy in files from my Eclipse project.

I have:

```
<project>
 <target name="deploy">
  <delete dir="/var/www/gds"/>
  <copy todir="/var/www/gds/src">
   <fileset dir="src">
   </fileset>
  </copy>
  <copy todir="/var/www/gds/">
   <fileset dir="web">
   </fileset>
  </copy>
 </target>
</project>
```

However ant doesn't appear to have root user privileges to copy into this directory. It works if I open Eclipse using 'sudo Eclipse' but I don't really want to be running Eclipse in root.

Is there a way I can get ant to copy into this directory?

Answer (score 1):

You could create an entry for the user you run Eclipse as in the /etc/sudoers file (using visudo or   your sudo permissions editor of choice) to allow ant to run as root without a password.  You would need to then get Eclipse to invoke "sudo ant" instead of just "ant" - I'm not familiar with Eclipse so maybe someone else can suggest if that's possible or not.  Failing that you could wrap the ant binary in a shell script that invokes sudo ant, and then tell Eclipse that that is the ant binary instead.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an ANT issue it's an file-system permission problem in Ubuntu.

Everything under `/var` is normally root access controlled. I agree that running your build as root is not the way to go :-)

I'd suggest creating a user directory under `/var/www` and then `read/write` your build files there.

For example:

```
sudo mkdir /var/www/gds
sudo chown myuser:myuser /var/www/gds
chmod 755 /var/www/gds
```

You still won't be allowed to delete the "gds" directory (because it's parent is owned by root) but you are allowed to delete everything inside it as follows

```
<delete>
    <fileset dir="/var/www/gds" includes="**"/>
<delete>
```